# Why my polar chart is rendered as a line chart? (Highcharts latest version)

Tags: highcharts

I followed some instructions and tutorials online but failed to create a polar chart.

It ends up a normal line chart.

What's wrong with my code? Any tips?

Thanks,

```js
  Highcharts.chart('container', {
    title: {
      text: null
    },
    legend: {
      enabled: false
    },
    tooltip: {
      pointFormat: '{point.y}'
    },
    pane: {
      size: '95%'
    },
    chart: {
      type: 'area',
      polar: true,
      spacingTop: 0
    },
    credits: {
      enabled: false
    },
    xAxis: {
      categories: ["John","Weta","Marry"],
      tickmarkPlacement: 'on',
      lineWidth: 2,
      labels: {
        style: {
          fontSize: window.screenshotMode ? '36px' : '18px'
        }
      }
    },
    yAxis: {
      gridLineInterpolation: 'polygon',
      lineWidth: 2,
      min: 0,
      max: 100,
      labels: {
        style: {
          fontSize: window.screenshotMode ? '36px' : '18px'
        }
      }
    },
    plotOptions: {
      series: {
        borderWidth: 4,
        borderColor: '#a00'
      }
    },
    series: [{
      data: [68,97,964]
    }]
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="height: 400px"></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[highchart-more](https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js) is required to run the polar charts so you will need to include `highchart-more.js` library.

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>
```

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    title: {
      text: null
    },
    legend: {
      enabled: false
    },
    tooltip: {
      pointFormat: '{point.y}'
    },
    pane: {
      size: '95%'
    },
    chart: {
      type: 'area',
      polar: true,
      spacingTop: 0
    },
    credits: {
      enabled: false
    },
    xAxis: {
      categories: ["John","Weta","Marry"],
      tickmarkPlacement: 'on',
      lineWidth: 2,
      labels: {
        style: {
          fontSize: window.screenshotMode ? '36px' : '18px'
        }
      }
    },
    yAxis: {
      gridLineInterpolation: 'polygon',
      lineWidth: 2,
      min: 0,
      max: 100,
      labels: {
        style: {
          fontSize: window.screenshotMode ? '36px' : '18px'
        }
      }
    },
    plotOptions: {
      series: {
        borderWidth: 4,
        borderColor: '#a00'
      }
    },
    series: [{
      data: [68,97,964]
    }]
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="height: 400px"></div>
```

API Reference : https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.polar

Comment: You are welcome.  Please select it as the answer if it works for you.